# Google Dart Center Paper Dialog on Screen Resize

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements

I'm currently attempting to center a PaperDialog depending on when the screen is resized. Right now, I have only figured out how to obtain the size of the screen but only once as it only collects this information on initialization.  I need it to be fully aware when the screen size changes.  The PaperDialog needs to somehow adhere to that and position itself in the very center of the screen but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.  The Dart code and markup are below.  Please let me know if you need more information.

Dart:

```dart
 var width = window.screen.width;
 var height = window.screen.height;

  _LOG.info("Browser width: "+width.toString());
  _LOG.info("Browser height: "+height.toString());
```

HTML:

```dart
<paper-dialog id="properties" style='background-color:#fbfbfb; margin: 0 auto; border-style: double; border-color: #FEB33F; position:fixed;'>

 <paper-tabs id="Tabs" noink="true" selected="{{page}}" style='width:250px; height:30px; color:#333333;'>
      <paper-tab id="sTab">S</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab id="uTab">U</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>

    <core-pages selected="{{page}}">
      <div id="s">
      <!--Page one -->
      </div>
      <div id="u">
      <!--Page two -->
      </div>
    </core-pages>
 </paper-dialog>
```

Comment: When you look at the demo `<paper-dialog>` seems to do this by default. The code has no special handling for this https://github.com/Polymer/paper-dialog/blob/master/demo.html. Maybe I misunderstood your question though.

Comment: It does do this, however, when the browser is small and you toggle it back and forth just once and then leave it open and then maximize the browser window again, the PaperDialog will actually stick to the left side of the screen.  I'll post the CSS in case that could be the issue.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with the paper-dialog demo page as well?

Comment: No, my guess is that it is because it is a fixed position if you look at the paper-dialog markup above..

Comment: Didn't scroll to the end. Can't you avoid adding it?

Comment: Well, I removed it, but it actually didn't make a difference.